# How do i make an image Black & White?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

How do i make an image Black & White? Using GPUImage library or default IOS framework. I tried code below but not getting expected result. Any third party library or code snippet help is highly appreciated

```
  -(UIImage *)convertOriginalImageToBWImage:(UIImage *)originalImage
{
    UIImage *newImage;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSapce = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, originalImage.size.width * originalImage.scale, originalImage.size.height * originalImage.scale, 8, originalImage.size.width * originalImage.scale, colorSapce, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height), [originalImage CGImage]);

    CGImageRef bwImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSapce);

    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bwImage];
    CGImageRelease(bwImage);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, NO, originalImage.scale);
    [resultImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height)];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: You'd be best to **post an image** of the look you want, because you are not familiar with common image processing terminology.  Click "edit" to do so

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of filters in the GPUImage framework that process a source image to a binary b&w one.

Here's the list of filters with the copy pasted description from the GPUImage framework homepage:

- **GPUImageMonochromeFilter**: Converts the image to a single-color version, based on the luminance of each pixel

  - *intensity*: The degree to which the specific color replaces the normal image color (0.0 - 1.0, with 1.0 as the default)
  - *color*: The color to use as the basis for the effect, with (0.6, 0.45, 0.3, 1.0) as the default.
- **GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter**: Pixels with a luminance above the threshold will 
  appear white, and those below will be black

  - *threshold*: The luminance threshold, from 0.0 to 1.0, with a default of 0.5
- **GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter**: Determines the local luminance around a pixel, then turns the pixel black if it is below that local luminance and white if above. This can be useful for picking out text under varying lighting conditions.

  - *blurRadiusInPixels*: A multiplier for the background averaging blur radius in pixels, with a default of 4.
- **GPUImageAverageLuminanceThresholdFilter**: This applies a thresholding operation where the threshold is continually adjusted based on the average luminance of the scene.

  - *thresholdMultiplier*: This is a factor that the average luminance will be multiplied by in order to arrive at the final threshold to use. By default, this is 1.0.

Answer (score 5):

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lambeau.jpg"];

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
GPUImageGrayscaleFilter *grayScaleFilter = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];

[stillImageSource addTarget:grayScaleFilter];
[stillImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture]
[stillImageSource processImage];

UIImage *currentFilteredVideoFrame = [grayScaleFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Comment: i need B&W not gray scale